# Markdown Link does not appear when preceded by [text]:

Tags: markdown

The following line does not display in markdown:

```
[Test]: [linkText](http://www.google.com)
```

However by adding a space after `linkText` it will display:

```
[Test]: [linkText ](http://www.google.com)
```

I can't seem to figure out what the issue here is. When `[Test]:` is removed the link will display fine.

Comment: Are you trying to include inline link or you want to define reference?

Comment: This might be helpful https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#links

Comment: @GevorgHarutyunyan an inline link. Thanks for that link, I believe the [Test]: text might cause markdown to think I am trying to add a reference link and think that [linkText] is the link?

`[Test]:` is just text to display, not trying to do anything else with that

Comment: Yes, your syntax is not matching to inline link pattern. I added correct pattern as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For inline links just use [linkText] (http://www.google.com) without space that I added to disable formatting on StackOverflow.